# .on and .off not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attached a click event of span in this way. The span is within a table.

```
 $("#tblImport").find("span").each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    appendData(this);
                });
            });
```

This event handler "appendData" makes an ajax request and gets the data.

```
 function appendData(prntSpan) {
            $(prntSpan).append(createElements());//ajax call.
            updateEvents(prntSpan);
        }
```

What I want is to detach this click event handler and attach a new one.
So I tried this.

```
function updateEvents(curntSpan) {
        $(curntSpan).off('click');//this works
        $(curntSpan).off('click', appendData);// but this does not work strange
        $(curntSpan).on('click', toggleData(curntSpan));//nor a new click handler is attached
    }
```

The function is called when the above line where .on is used is executed, but afterwards when you click on the span no event is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong syntax in `.on()` function check [it](http://api.jquery.com/on/). So In my opinion you should change your code for:

```
$("#tblImport span").click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                appendData(this);
            });
```

this has cleaner syntax.

```
function updateEvents(curntSpan) {
        $(curntSpan).off('click');//this works
        $("#tblImport").on('click', curntSpan, function() { toggleData(curntSpan); });
    }
```

Comment: just one last thing how can we avoid this event getting triggered at the time it is getting registered and why this is not getting triggered after you click it again.

Comment: for prevent triggered second event you can use `e.stopPropagation();` and add `e` parameter to function in `click` event. Look at update which I made.

Comment: nope its not working and also the event is not firing from the next time.

Comment: If it is not work for you I suggest you to check do you do not have any errors in function which you invoked in. There you have fiddle with alerts http://jsfiddle.net/mhVN9/10/

Comment: @ankur, you were missing a function(){} wrapper around the toggleData call.  this caused it to execute the function, not pass a reference to the click event.  i've fixed it int this answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateEvents(curntSpan) {
    /* ... */
    $(curntSpan).on('click', toggleData(curntSpan));
}
```

What this will do is this:

1. Evaluate `$(curntSpan)`, yielding a jQuery object
2. Access its `.on` attribute
3. Evaluate `'click'` and `toggleData(curntSpan)`, yielding a string and something else
4. Call the `.on` attribute with the string and the something else from the previous step as arguments

I think what you want instead is something like this:

```
function updateEvents(curntSpan) {
    /* ... */
    $(curntSpan).on('click', function(){ toggleData(curntSpan) });
}
```

In step 3, this will evaluate `function(){ toggleData(curntSpan) }` instead of `toggleData(curntSpan)`—the result being a function that calls `toggleData(curntSpan)` when called (i.e. when the `click` event is fired).

The general rules:

1. Whenever you a function is called, its arguments are evaluated
2. When you evaluate a function *call*, e.g. `f(x)`, you run the function and take the result
3. When you evaluate a function *expression*, e.g. `function() { /* f(x) */ }`, the result is simply that function (here: one that takes no arguments and which has an empty body, due to it being commented out).

The same logic is why you do `$(function() { /* ... */ })` rather than `$(f(x))` to have some code run when the page has been "booted".

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(curntSpan).off('click', appendData);
```

will not work as you don't put appendData as handler at the first place.Into handler you put anonymous function within you run appendData, but not appendData itself

Comment: so what would that piece of code will be , also .on is also not working.

Comment: try `$("#tblImport").find("span").on('click',appendData)` in the first place and change prntSpan into this in appendData. Then .off should work too